# Texture Not Displayed: OpenGL (JOGL)

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I am trying to draw several images on screen. However, images by themself are not displayed. Only area where they have to be has different to background color. Can you help me to find error? I saw few topic, where simillar projlem was cause by looking on texture from oppoisite side. But i dont understand how to change side prperly.

```
package game; 

import java.awt.BorderLayout; 
import java.awt.Color; 
import java.awt.Dimension; 
import java.awt.DisplayMode; 
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice; 
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment; 
import java.awt.Point; 
import java.awt.Rectangle; 
import java.awt.Toolkit; 
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent; 
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent; 
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter; 
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent; 
import java.io.File; 
import java.io.IOException; 
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.Collections; 



import javax.media.opengl.GL2; 
import javax.media.opengl.GLAutoDrawable; 
import javax.media.opengl.GLCapabilities; 
import javax.media.opengl.GLEventListener; 
import javax.media.opengl.GLProfile; 
import javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas; 
import javax.media.opengl.glu.GLU; 
import javax.swing.AbstractAction; 
import javax.swing.ActionMap; 
import javax.swing.InputMap; 
import javax.swing.JFrame; 
import javax.swing.JOptionPane; 
import javax.swing.JPanel; 
import javax.swing.KeyStroke; 

import com.jogamp.opengl.util.FPSAnimator; 
import com.jogamp.opengl.util.texture.Texture; 
import com.jogamp.opengl.util.texture.TextureIO; 

public class StartingClass implements GLEventListener { 
        private static GraphicsEnvironment graphicsEnviorment; 

        private GLU glu = new GLU(); 

        private int texture; 
        private static int B_WIDTH = 800; 
        private static int B_HEIGHT = 600; 
        private Dog dog; 
        private Wolf wolf; 
        private ArrayList<Sheep> sheeps; 
        private boolean ingame; 

        @Override 
        public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) { 
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                final GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2(); 
                gl.glClear(GL2.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL2.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 
                // Clear // The // Screen // And // The 
                // Depth 
                // Buffer 
                gl.glLoadIdentity(); // Reset The View 
                gl.glBindTexture(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, dog.getTexture()); 
                gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_QUADS); 
                // Front Face 
                Rectangle rect = dog.getBounds(); 
                gl.glTexCoord2f(rect.x, rect.y); 
                gl.glVertex3f(rect.x, rect.y, 0.0f); 
                gl.glTexCoord2f(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y); 
                gl.glVertex3f(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y, 0.0f); 
                gl.glTexCoord2f(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height); 
                gl.glVertex3f(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height, 0.0f); 
                gl.glTexCoord2f(rect.x, rect.y + rect.height); 
                gl.glVertex3f(rect.x, rect.y + rect.height, 0.0f); 
                gl.glEnd(); 


                gl.glFlush(); 

        } 

        @Override 
        public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable drawable) { 
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 

        } 

        @Override 
        public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable) { 
                dog = new Dog(B_WIDTH / 2, B_HEIGHT / 2); 

                final GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2(); 

                gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D); 
                try { 
                        File im = new File("src/game/dog.jpg"); 
                        Texture t = TextureIO.newTexture(im, true); 
                        dog.setTexture(t.getTextureObject(gl)); 
                } catch (IOException e) { 
                        e.printStackTrace(); 
                } 

        } 

        @Override 
        public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable drawable, int x, int y, int width, 
                        int height) { 
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                final GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2(); 

                if (height <= 0) 
                        height = 1; 
                final float h = (float) width / (float) height; 
                gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height); 
                gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_PROJECTION); 
                gl.glLoadIdentity(); 
                gl.glOrtho(0, width, height, 0, 0, 1); 

                gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_MODELVIEW); 
                gl.glLoadIdentity(); 
        } 

        /** 
         * @param args 
         */ 
        public static void main(String[] args) { 
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                // setUp open GL version 2 
                final GLProfile profile = GLProfile.get(GLProfile.GL2); 
                GLCapabilities capabilities = new GLCapabilities(profile); 

                // The canvas 
                final GLCanvas glcanvas = new GLCanvas(capabilities); 
                StartingClass r = new StartingClass(); 
                glcanvas.addGLEventListener(r); 
                glcanvas.setSize(B_WIDTH, B_HEIGHT); 

                final FPSAnimator animator = new FPSAnimator(glcanvas, 300, true); 

                final JFrame frame = new JFrame("sheppard"); 

                frame.getContentPane().add(glcanvas); 

                // Shutdown 
                frame.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() { 
                        @Override 
                        public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent windowEvent) { 
                                if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, 
                                                "Are you sure to close this window?", 
                                                "Really Closing?", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, 
                                                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE) == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) { 
                                        if (animator.isStarted()) 
                                                animator.stop(); 
                                        System.exit(0); 
                                } 
                        } 
                }); 

                frame.setSize(frame.getContentPane().getPreferredSize()); 
                /** 
                 * Centers the screen on start up 
                 * 
                 */ 
                graphicsEnviorment = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(); 

                GraphicsDevice[] devices = graphicsEnviorment.getScreenDevices(); 

                Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize(); 

                int windowX = Math.max(0, (screenSize.width - frame.getWidth()) / 2); 
                int windowY = Math.max(0, (screenSize.height - frame.getHeight()) / 2); 

                frame.setLocation(windowX, windowY); 
                /** 
                                 * 
                                 */ 
                frame.setVisible(true); 
                /* 
                 * Time to add Button Control 
                 */ 
                JPanel p = new JPanel(); 
                p.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0, 0)); 
                frame.add(p, BorderLayout.SOUTH); 
                frame.setResizable(false); 
                animator.start(); 
        } 

        //methods to generate sheeps' positions 


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a `GL_TEXTURE_2D`. What are the bounds coming back from `dog.getBounds()`? When using `GL_TEXTURE_2D`, the texture coordinates should be normalized (between 0 and 1). Since you've set the current matrix (which I assume is the ModelView matrix?) to identity, the entire window should be in the range -1 to 1 in x and y.

I wouldn't expect the bounds of an image to be useful as both texture coordinates and vertex coordinates in most cases. For example, an image might be 640x480, but you want to display it in a rectangle that happens to be at coordinates (-5,-5) and extends to (15, 10). The texture coords in this case would still be from 0-1 in both directions for a `GL_TEXTURE_2D`.

I'd check what all the coordinates involved are and see if they make sense the way you've set up the world that OpenGL is drawing to the window.